# When I mark a property as transient, does the type matter?

Tags: iphone, core-data

For example, I make a fullName property and set it to transient. Does it matter what data type that property is, in this case? For example, does it matter if it's set to int or string?

As far as I get it, a transient property is almost "ignored" by Core Data. I make my accessors for that and when someone accesses fullName, I simply construct a string and return that.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the type does matter because the `NSManagedObject` will still generate the *ivar* (for lack of a better term) for you internally.